# How can I make the text stay on the right of the jQuery UI accordion icon?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to make the text stay on the right of the jQuery UI accordion icon.

This is how it is rendered.

[image]

Here is the markup, I' m using bootstrap as you can see

```
<div class="panel" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-toggle">
                2015
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="span7">
                      <a>
                      <span></span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="span3">
                      <a>
                  </td>
                </tr>                    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here the jQuery script

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion(
                {
                    header: ".panel-heading",
                    heightStyle: "content"
                });
        })
</script>
```

Could someone tell me how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to apply style `display : inline-block;`

to the accordion icon and to your text block ?